# Cordova/PhoneGap and iOS Session Persistence

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm running a Cordova app with Angular on the front-end and Node.js/Express + Passport on the backend. Everything is dandy, but my user sessions don't persist on iOS. Closing and reopening the app on an iOS effectively logs a user out.

How can I persist the session/cookies on an iOS device? Can I achieve this with JavaScript or will I have to change settings in the iOS build?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but here goes:

Anything you want to have survive an app restart will need to be stored in [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or something similar.

Your app's state is not magically persisted, just like a regular website doesn't automatically remembers you (your data is often stored in cookies).

Comment: It works without an issue on Android - I guess my questions has to do with how and WHAT to store in localstorage. I'm guessing the connect.sid value?